# Doctrine delete With Querybuilder an IN

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
    $qb = $this->getDoctrine ()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete('MainBundle:StatisticUser', 'u');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('sessionid', array_keys($sessionidsToTruncate)));
    var_dump($qb->getQuery());
    $qb->getQuery()->execute();

private '_dql' => string 'DELETE MainBundle:StatisticUser u WHERE sessionid IN('asdfghjkl')' (length=75)
```

but i get an error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 50 near 'sessionid IN': Error: 'sessionid' is not defined.
```

Can anyone point me to the Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution with trial and error:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u.sessionid', array_keys($sessionidsToTruncate)));
```